# Newly added featured products not showing in Woo Carousel Slider

Tags: woocommerce, carousel, storefront

after Woocommerce updated to 3.0, newly added featured products are not showing in Woo Carousel Slider. It is showing only previously added featured products. It is not a problem of the plugin as I changed the plugin and ended up having the same result. Do any one have any solution regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. driving me nuts for a few days and then I thought about it.. I had updated WooCommerce, but not the carousel. lol. Check your plugins to make sure all of them are up to date.